# computing cohomology algebra of connected sum of two real projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Could someone tell me what is the cohomology algebra $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n \# \mathbb{R}P^n; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ and how to compute it. Here $\#$ is the connected sum.

Thanks.

Comment: First compute the cohomology groups using Mayer-Vietoris. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31287/homology-of-punctured-projective-space

Answer (score 2):

Given two compact connected differential manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ of dimension $n$, the reduced homology with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients of their connected sum is given by
$$\tilde H_i(M_1 \#M_2) =\tilde H_i(M_1) \oplus \tilde H_i(\#M_2) \quad \text {for}\;\; i\lt  n-1$$
$$ H_{n-1}(M_1 \#M_2) = H_{n-1}(M_1) \oplus \ H_{n-1}(\#M_2)$$  *if* one of $M_1, M_2 $at least is orientable
$$H_n(M_1 \#M_2) = \mathbb Z   \; \text {or } \;0$$ according as both $M_1, M_2$ are orientable or not.
This results from Mayer-Vietoris.
You should   then calculate cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb Z/2$ by the universal coefficient theorem.
*Warning*: if both $M_1,M_2$ are non-orientable (in your case if  your projective space $\mathbb P^n$ is even-dimensional), I am not sure that $M_1 \#M_2$ is even well defined, i.e. is independent of the choices made in the construction of the connected sum.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want to compute $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n \# \mathbb{R}P^n; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ when $n$ is odd. I am interested in knowing the algebra structure and computing the product seems tricky.

Comment: For $n=3$, I computed that $$H^i(\mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}_2)=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}_2 & \mbox{if } i=0\\
\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mbox{if } i=1 \\
\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mbox{if } i=2 \\
\mathbb{Z}_2 & \mbox{if } i=3.\\
\end{cases}$$ But I am not able to determine the product. Could someone help me.